# Can I access event handlers from ref OTSession

Tags: react-native, opentok

I'm trying acess events coming from OTSession by ref like `streamCreated`, `signal`, `streamDestroyed`. Is that possible like that: 
[How I think it should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPoSt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manik here from TokBox.

You cannot access the events through a ref because we pass the events to the native layer and set the listeners when mounting the component, however, you can listen to the events like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { OTSession, OTPublisher, OTSubscriber } from 'opentok-react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.apiKey = '';
    this.sessionId = '';
    this.token = '';
    this.sessionEventHandlers = {
      streamCreated: event => {
        console.log("stream created", event);
      },
      streamDestroyed: event => {
        console.log("stream destroyed", event);
      },
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <OTSession apiKey={this.apiKey} sessionId={this.sessionId} token={this.token} eventHandlers={this.sessionEventHandlers}>
          <OTPublisher style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
          <OTSubscriber style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
        </OTSession>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.